# transfer funds from Mt.Gox after the crash of 2014

Tags: mtgox, funds, money-transfer

By now, 25/03/2014, you can view your funds on the Mt. Gox website. I have some euro's parked over there. Is there a way to transfer them. Is there a procedure you can follow?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No.

MtGox assets are currently frozen and they have lost a lot of customer funds, both fiat and Bitcoin. Until further notice you can consider your euros lost.

Contact your lawyer and ask them to write a claim to official MtGox address. Also some local Bitcoin communities are preparing class-action (or similar) lawsuits against MtGox and its subsidiaries.